# Is it possible to change the logging level of delayed_job separately from the main Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'd like to use the `DEBUG` logging level for my Rails app on our staging server, but I'd like `delayed_job` (which logs a `SELECT` statement to the main Rails log every 10 seconds) to log at `INFO` level, so I don't get these `delayed_job` `SELECT` statements in there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

`RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` is deprecated in 3.x versions of Rails, so you'll need to use the following in script/delayed_job before the `Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize` call:

```
::Rails.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

Comment: undefined method `INFO' for Logger:Class (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.  What I did in my script that runs Delayed::Job.worker.start was to add, before the worker starts:

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.level = Logger::INFO
```

This worked for me.